# Highlight specific word which is not a part of another word using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript

Let's consider a string named **str*, which is defined as :

```
let str = "I am looking for the forum";
```

And a function named **highlight** which can be used something as :

```
let f = highlight(str);
console.log(f); 
// Expected Result : I am looking <b>for</b> the forum.
```

I tried to make the function with regex. My try :

```
const highlight = (val) => {
 return val = val.replace(/for/gim, "<b>for</b>");
};
```

But the output was :

```
I am looking <b>for</b> the <b>for</b>um
```

So, how can I solve it ?

Comment: Use the regex word boundary `\b`?

Comment: use /\bfor\b/ instead of /for/